# Creating Kafka Custom Authorizer with Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have setup a customer authorizer by setting below properties in server.properties
authorizer.class.name= {package_name}.myAuthorizer

And myAuthorizer.java implements from kafka.security.auth.Authorizer

And included the myAuthorizer.jar in the libs directory.

It is working as expected but I am wondering if I can include the application properties using Dependency Injection.

I have tried to migrate the current working myAuthorizer to Spring project and running on the IDE is successful, but in the broker I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: {package_name}.myAuthorizer
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadClass(Utils.java:374)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:363)
at kafka.security.authorizer.AuthorizerUtils$.createAuthorizer(AuthorizerUtils.scala:38)
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1417)
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1273)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:68)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

For the custom Authorizer, can I build as Spring Java project? Or should I leave it as Java project?

Comment: Sounds like you're not putting your packaged code on the classpath correctly. Running things from an IDE does that for you, and is not representative of how code will actually work on external clients... And given your error doesn't mention Spring, I'm not sure that's the issue

Comment: Non-spring project saves the classes as {package_name}/myAuthorizer.class
and Spring project saves the classes as BOOT-INF/classes/{package_name}/myAuthorizer.class
How can I refer to this class in Kafka server.properties?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with how you're packaging the JAR. Are you using Maven?

Comment: Yes, I am using mvn install to build jar file

Comment: You've created an executable JAR format, not a library https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html